# Reputation change bug

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I recently answered this question ([Simple quadratic function, but can't understand the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4410589/1012971)).I got 24 upvotes as well as my answer(edited by @Dan) was accepted; but my reputation change due for this question shows +235 instead of +255. Is that a bug or any rule I am not aware of?

Comment: There is a daily rep cap of 200. This excludes any rep earned via Bounty or acceptance. Thus on first day you get 200+15 and later 20 more.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Does that mean I will get +20 tommorow or it can be anytime later?

Comment: No, you don't get it later. You are not allowed to earn more than 200 in a single day via voting. Any extra voting on same day will not lead to any rep. Vote count will increase however.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ohk Thanks for informing about this rule.

Comment: I will remove the "bug" tag.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yeah sure.

Comment: You can find some pointers to info about the daily reputation cap in the corresponding tag-info [on this meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/daily-reputation-limit/info) and also [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/daily-reputation-limit/info).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for the links.